# TFS checkout programmatically from different machine

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS API to programmatically checkout and checkin files ,I have a TFS user user1 with password p1 which have workspace w1 on machine A
how can I programmatically -from another machine "B" - check out or check in file at user1's workspace w1 ?

Comment: You can't if you're using local workspaces.  You can get the file from their network share if they have their projects folder shared; but there's no way to get a file that the user is working on that they haven't committed yet. You could get locally committed files if they were using `git` as their source control store instead of `tfvcs`.

Comment: the workspace w1 on machine A is just a centralized server that contains all files , and any user that needs to check in or check out any file must do this locally from his machine(without having local workspace or TFS mapping on his local machine) , the problem is that TFS doesn't accept to check in or check out files on that server from my local machine although I have all the necessary info like remote TFS user ID & password and remote workspace path

Comment: What steps are you taking, and what errors do you get?